# Jenkins CI Post-build Actions - How to push to Stash

Tags: git, github, jenkins, bitbucket-server

I have Jenkins set up to monitor a private GitHub repo and currently is performing builds when I commit to GitHub using the GitHub Hook. Is it possible to set up an action to then push the same code to a Stash repo using 'Post-build Actions'?

So just to clarify, I have Jenkins detecting new code that is pushed to the GitHub and I would like to fire off an additional action after the build, using Jenkins to push the same code to a Stash repo.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Post-build "Git Publisher" step will push the current HEAD to a designated remote on a git repository specified among your "Git Repositories".

To configure: add both your private and the stash repository to Git Repositories, specify the "branch to build" to the target branch from your private re.
Create a Git Publisher post-build action, telling it to push to the desired branch on the Stash repo.

If that doesn't work, you can always fall back on the "execute shell" build step and specify the git commands in the script, but that would not be ideal.